# Pivotal GemFire 9.3.0: Spring Data GemFire XML config in GemFire cluster

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I am migrating my GemFire cluster from 8.2.7 (with Spring Data GemFire 1.6.0.RELEASE) to Pivotal GemFire 9.3.0 (SDG 2.0.7.RELEASE). I was using `spring-context.xml` (declared under the `initializer` tag in `cache.xml`) to initialize the Regions while starting cache servers on each node.

When I try to reuse the same `spring-context.xml` for Pivotal GemFire 9.3.0, my Spring beans tag is not identified by the `gfsh` command and I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 107; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)

        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
```

spring-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-geode.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
        <prop key="log-level">config</prop>
        <prop key="locators">hostA[10334],hostB[10334]</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="mappingPdxSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer"/>

    <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties" pdx-serializer-ref="mappingPdxSerializer"/>

    <gfe:replicated-region id="Product">
    </gfe:replicated-region>

    <gfe:replicated-region id="ProductCustomer">
    </gfe:replicated-region>

</beans>
```

I updated the XML schema paths from "`gemfire`" to "`geode`" based on Spring documentation for `spring-data-gemfire:2.0.7.RELEASE`.

Trying with GF 9.1.1 and SDGF 2.0.7. (SDGF jar is placed in lib)

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1:/opt/jdk/1.8.0_71l64/bin/:/var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1/bin/
export GEMFIRE=/var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1/


for i in `ls  /var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1/lib/*.jar`
do
  CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${i}
done
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1/config
#echo $CLASSPATH

if [ -e "/var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml" ]; then
   echo "File exists"
else
 echo "File does not exist"
fi


gfsh start server --name=server1 --server-port=40405 --classpath=$CLASSPATH --spring-xml-location=/var/tmp/user/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml  --locators=hostA[10334],hostB[10334] --mcast-port=0
```

**UPDATE:**

`FileNotFoundException` thrown :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [var/tmp/sn17180/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)

        ... 17 more
```

I have given permission to all the files and -e "/" in my script is also printing "File exists".

UPDATE:

cache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cache xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd"
       version="1.0">

  <region name="Parent" refid="REPLICATE">
    <region name="Child" refid="REPLICATE"/>
  </region>

</cache>
```

gemfire-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
        <prop key="locators">xyz[10334],xyx[10334]</prop>
        <prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="autoSerializer" class="org.apache.geode.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer"/>

    <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties" cache-xml-location="cache.xml" pdx-serializer-ref="autoSerializer" pdx-read-serialized="true"/>   

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivotal GemFire stopped shipping with *Spring Data GemFire* in the `$GEMFIRE_HOME/lib` directory as of the 9.x release series.  There are 2 primary reasons for this.

1) First, it was somewhat of a conundrum that Pivotal GemFire depended on SDG, which was entirely for `gfsh>start server --name=SpringConfiguredServer --spring-xml-location-/path/to/spring/context.xml`, when SDG depended on Pivotal GemFire, which clearly forms a circular dependency.

2) Pivotal GemFire lags significantly behind the current state of the *Spring* ecosystem when it pertains to versions.  Even the latest release, 9.3.0, ships with outdated *Spring* JARs, e.g. core *Spring Framework* `4.3.13.RELEASE`, when core *Spring Framework* `4.3.17.RELEASE` is already available as well as `5.0.6.RELEASE`, with 5.1 on the horizon.

Having said that, it is still possible to configure and bootstrap your Pivotal GemFire Servers with *Spring* when started from *Gfsh* using the `start server` command, `--spring-xml-location` option.  You simply need to download the [appropriate version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-GemFire-to-GemFire-Version-Compatibility) of SDG based on the Pivotal GemFire version you are using (e.g. (9.3.0)) and put SDG on the classpath when starting the server.

> NOTE: currently, *SDG 2.1.0.M3* (SD *Lovelace*) is the only version based on Pivotal GemFire 9.3 and later; currently set to 9.5.0.
>
> NOTE: also not, I don't specifically recall whether I ran into any API breaking changes between upgrading SDG Lovelace progressively from Pivotal GemFire 9.3, then to 9.4 and finally arriving at 9.5.  If you have trouble with `spring-data-gemfire:2.1.0.M3`, you can also use `spring-data-gemfire:2.1.0.M2` which was [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.1.0.M2/pom.xml#L25) Pivotal GemFire 9.3 at the time.

So following the recipe above, you would do the following...

```
gfsh> start server --name=SpringConfiguredServer --classpath=/file/system/path/to/spring-data-gemfire22.1.0.M3.jar --spring-xml-location=/classpath/to/your/spring-context.xml
```

This should work!

Also, you do not need to switch schemas from "gemfire" to "geode".  When you are using Spring Data GemFire, then use the "spring-gemfire" schema.  When you are using Spring Data Geode, then use the "spring-geode" schema.  Either will probably work, but...

Hope this helps!

-j

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. Now I am trying with Gemfire 9.1.1 and SDGF- 2.0.7. I am getting "file does not exist" IO exception . Please check the updated post.

Comment: Hi Sudharsan - So, as you can see from the _Stack Trace_, the Spring context, by default (a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` instance when Spring XML is used) searches for your `spring-context.xml` in the CLASSPATH, which matches the ApplicationContext type.  This is why you see the `o.s.core.io.ClassPathResource` in the _Stack Trace_.  I suspect your `spring-context.xml` is coming from the file system, hence... `var/tmp/sn17180/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml`)?  In which case, you need to tell Spring this by prefixing the path to `spring-context.xml` with `file:///`.  ...

Comment: This effectively overrides the `ApplicationContext` types default resource search location to be other than the "*default*", which, again, for a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is to search the CLASSPATH for the XML config.  If the `ApplicationContext` were a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`, then Spring would search for the XML config in the file system.  However, even though a `ApplicationContext` defaults the resource path based on type, you can override it with the resource specifier, as described in *Table 10 - Resource strings* at this link ...

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-resourceloader

Comment: So, I think in your case, the URL to `spring-context.xml` would be... `file:///var/tmp/sn17180/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml`.  Note, a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instance will still be used, but the `file://` resource specifier tells the context to search the file system instead of the CLASSPATH (the default). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much John for all the explanation. I got it worked.

Comment: John. Hope you are doing great. Can I give spring-xml-location property in gemfire.properties?. I am able to find cache xml property from the pivotal docs but not for doing context. Please help.

Comment: Not `spring-xml-location`, but you can set `cache-xml-file` (see here: http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/reference/topics/gemfire_properties.html).  Of course, above, you are using SDG's GFE namespace so you could simply set `<gfe:cache cache-xml-location=".."/>`, too. :)

Comment: John. if the cluster config bootstrap cache through cache.xml  , can peer or client instance access the same cache and regions through SDGF?

Comment: The cache is a Singleton, always.  So, it does not matter if the cache is created by GemFire native APIs, `cache.xml` or Spring config.  To access the Regions created by `cache.xml`, have a look at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:region:lookup:auto.  This also works when your application is a peer cache member in the cluster and you have enabled the Cluster Configuration Service in the Locator and peers.

Comment: ok thanks. updated the post with cache.xml and gemfire-config.xml. When the cache server starts, can i input gemfire-config.xml in "cache-xml-location" gemfire property?. will it bootstrap cache and regions with expected PDX serializer?

Comment: It cannot find your `cache.xml` (i.e. var/tmp/sn17180/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml) because the Gfsh `start server` command, `--spring-xml-location` option looks in the classpath, first.  If you want to find the Spring XML config in the file system, then you need to use 1 of Spring's Resource access schemes (e.g. `file:///var/tmp/sn17180/gemfire/9.1.1/config/spring-context.xml`).  See Table 10 in (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-resourceloader) for more details.

Comment: If my cache server is started through Java API (server launcher), what is the property i should use to give my "spring-context.xml"?

Comment: Then it would by `spring-xml-location`, or this property on `ServerLauncher` (http://gemfire-97-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/distributed/ServerLauncher.Builder.html#setSpringXmlLocation-java.lang.String-).